# Recursion segmentation fault and StackGuard

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

Lets say I have a function that all it does is calling itself without any termination.

```
myFunction(){
    myFunction()
}
```

if I run a program containing this function, I will eventually get a segmentation fault. Why does this happen? Running out of stack space?

Also, can StackGuard protect against this fault? Why or why not?

Comment: If you attempt to run that code, what should happen is that it doesn't even build because of the syntax errors.

Comment: This recursion has no stopping condition. What would you expect?

Comment: Stack is a limited resource. On Windows the default stack size for a process is a single MB. And the only way to protect against it is to have a termination condition that actually terminates the recursion.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Well, what I would expect for indefinite recursion is a stack overflow.

Comment: @SamIam Well, the question was for the OP :) But it actually doesn't have to be the behavior, as it is a tail recursion, easily unrolled to a loop.

Comment: And StackGuard is something different that doesn't protect against "infinite" recursion. It is for protecting against *stack smashing* and similar exploits that can rewrite the existing stack, not against stack overflows like this.

Comment: @SamIam you got the idea

Comment: @EugeneSh  running out of space

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you explain more? is not stackguard  about canary and it happens before the function returns?

Comment: It is tempting to think that testing for a stack guard either below the stack pointer, or with a local undefined variable, could be made before the next recursive call is taken. It might work sometimes: until an interrupt overwrites the stack guard making it undetectable.

Comment: @Timmy Yes, but a function call doesn't overwrite the canary, it simply creates a fresh new frame on the stack, with a fresh new set of canaries. In fact using stack canaries will make the stack overflow faster since there's less space for the stack frames.

Comment: A compiler could optimize this code to be `myFunction(){
    while(1);
}`.  No need to overflow the stack.  C does not specify a seg fault must occur.

Comment: It should also be noted that a stack isn't needed or even *required* by the C specification. It just so happens that a stack works very well to implement function calls and local variable lifetime-handling. But it is perfectly fine to have a stack-less implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As the recursion is infinite, and for each call the return address and base pointer (frame pointer) at least are pushed onto the stack, you will eventually run out of stack space, or more generally, run out of memory, as memory is a finite resource.

Nothing can guard against this because it is the programmer who "designed" this infinite recursion. What would you expect "protect against this fault"? As I said it is not a fault as it is the program's design. You just run out of a finite resource, causing the OS to abort the program.

---

EDIT: the following is an example of intercepting the seg fault (untested, based on VC2008 doc):

```
jmp_buf home;

void myFunction(void)
{
    myFunction();
}
void SegvHandler(int signal)
{
    longjmp(home);
}
int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, SegvHandler);
    if (setjmp(home)) {
        printf("Oops...\n)
        return 1;
    }
    myFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

---

TEST: after testing in VC2008, it appears not to be possible to catch this error. The reason seems to be/could be that: first the stack overflow occurrs, and now there is no more stack space to call another function, the signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call a function it will cause a new stack frame to be created in memory for that function call. This stack disappears when the function returns. As your function does not return and keeps calling new calls it will keep creating stack frames which means eventually you run out of memory to keep those stack frames.